# Is the .value property of HTMLSelectElement reliable

Tags: javascript

Consider an html select box with an id of "MySelect".

Is it safe to get the value of the selected option like this:

```
document.getElementById("MySelect").value;
```

rather than this:

```
var Sel = document.getElementById("MySelect");
var MyVal = Sel.option[MyVal.selectedIndex].value;
```

It appears to be safe but I've never seen documentation on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't widely supported with old browsers

If want to be safe you can use `selectedIndex` with the `option` as you stated in your question.

You can be sure you'll get value from below, if your worried.

`document.nform.nselect.options[document.nform.nselect .selectedIndex].value`

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago, this wasn't cross-browser safe. But these days, I don't know.

Is using jQuery an option?
Because this:

```
$("#MySelect").val();
```

is totally cross-browser safe.

Comment: But these days, I don't know, haha

Comment: "It wasn't widely supported with old browsers" is far better. How about now? ;o)

Comment: I am actually using JQuery but it is inside of an each callback and it seems much more efficient to just say this.value rather than wrapping it in a totally new Jquery object.